# group width on xslt elements (xslt 1.0)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

ХМL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<page>
<elements>
<element>
<data>
<Styles Name="default">
<Style Url="/css.css" Browser="default" Version="default"/>
</Styles>
</data>
</element>
<element type="Digillect.WB.Web.Elements.Site.SiteStructureElement">
<config StartLevel="0" MaxDepth="3" UseItemVisibility="false">
<monikers>
<moniker store="asdasd"/>
</monikers>
</config>
<data ParentPath="/">
</data>
</element>


<element name="bids">
<config>
<Object Id="1b61995a-6e22-4b09-af5f-9a50cdaa7863"/>
<Object Id="baa1d3df-0510-4f68-8a41-1b9b22587134"/>
</config>
<data>

<Object Id="id2" Name="Paris">
<Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
</Object>
<Object Id="id1" Name="Lion">
<Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
</Object>
<Object Id="id3" Name="Berlin">
<Property Name="COUNTRY">Germany</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://germany.gr</Property>
</Object>

</data>
</element>
</elements>
</page>
```

It is necessary to bring the country's selectors sorted by name and get rid of duplicates:

```
<select>
<option value="http://germany.gr">Germany</option>
<option value="france">France</option>
</select>
```

That is, if the country meets a few times, in value = specify the id. If once, then specify the link

Description grouped as follows: if a country meets several times

Code:

```
<div id="france">
<p> <a href="/index.php?id=id1">Lion</a></p>
<p><a href="/index.php?id=id2">Paris</a></p>
</div>
```

If the country meets once - did not write

Comment: Please, edit the question and add the complete wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 1.0 you can use Muechian grouping to perform grouping respectively to identify and eliminate duplicates; the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="data/Object" use="@Id"/>

<xsl:template match="data">
  <select>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', @Id)[1])]"/>
  </select>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', @Id)[1]) and key('k1', @Id)[2]]" mode="desc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object[key('k1', @Id)[2]]">
  <option value="{@Id}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY']"/>
  </option>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object[not(key('k1', @Id)[2])]">
  <option value="{Property[@Name = 'WWW']}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY']"/>
  </option>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object" mode="desc">
  <div id="city_{@Id}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', @Id)/Property[@Name = 'NAME']" mode="desc"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object/Property" mode="desc">
  <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms the input

```
<page>
<elements>
<element name="bids">
<data>

<Object Id="id1">
<Property Name="NAME" Order="0">Paris</Property>
<Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
</Object>
<Object Id="id1">
<Property Name="NAME" Order="0">Lion</Property>
<Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
</Object>
<Object Id="id2">
<Property Name="NAME" Order="0">Berlin</Property>
<Property Name="COUNTRY">Germany</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://germany.gr</Property>
</Object>

</data>
</element>
</elements>
</page>
```

into

```
<select>
   <option value="id1">France</option>
   <option value="http://germany.gr">Germany</option></select><div id="city_id1">
   <p>Paris</p>
   <p>Lion</p>
</div>
```

[edit]

Here is an adapted stylesheet that uses a different key to try to implement the changed requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="data/Object" use="Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY']"/>

<xsl:template match="data[Object]">
  <select>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY'])[1])]"/>
  </select>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY'])[1]) and key('k1', Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY'])[2]]" mode="desc"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object[key('k1', Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY'])[2]]">
  <option value="{Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY']}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY']"/>
  </option>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object[not(key('k1', Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY'])[2])]">
  <option value="{Property[@Name = 'WWW']}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY']"/>
  </option>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object" mode="desc">
  <div id="{Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY']}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY'])" mode="link">
      <xsl:sort select="@Name"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/Object" mode="link">
  <p>
    <a href="/index.php?id={@Id}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
    </a>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply that stylesheet to the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<page>
<elements>
<element>
<data>
<Styles Name="default">
<Style Url="/css.css" Browser="default" Version="default"/>
</Styles>
</data>
</element>
<element type="Digillect.WB.Web.Elements.Site.SiteStructureElement">
<config StartLevel="0" MaxDepth="3" UseItemVisibility="false">
<monikers>
<moniker store="asdasd"/>
</monikers>
</config>
<data ParentPath="/">
</data>
</element>


<element name="bids">
<config>
<Object Id="1b61995a-6e22-4b09-af5f-9a50cdaa7863"/>
<Object Id="baa1d3df-0510-4f68-8a41-1b9b22587134"/>
</config>
<data>

<Object Id="id2" Name="Paris">
<Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
</Object>
<Object Id="id1" Name="Lion">
<Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
</Object>
<Object Id="id3" Name="Berlin">
<Property Name="COUNTRY">Germany</Property>
<Property Name="WWW" >http://germany.gr</Property>
</Object>

</data>
</element>
</elements>
</page>
```

the result is

```
<select>
   <option value="France">France</option>
   <option value="http://germany.gr">Germany</option></select><div id="France">
   <p><a href="/index.php?id=id1">Lion</a></p>
   <p><a href="/index.php?id=id2">Paris</a></p>
</div>
```

so the `option` elements are grouped as required (although I couldn't figure out what determines the sort order) and the `p` elements contain links with the `@Id` value incorporated.

Comment: Hmmm. If more complex xml - trouble. I do not have enough knowledge to fix. I put the full version.

Comment: Well you can edit the input sample but then we also need to know what exactly you want to do with the other elements so edit the result sample as well to explain what result you want.

Comment: I corrected the xml and html. Id everywhere is different and the group will have on the country

Comment: I will edit my post to try to adapt the suggested solution to your changed requirements.

Comment: Excellent! What I want, but I do not understand writing [generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1',Property[@Name='REGION'])[1]) and key('k1',Property[@Name='REGION'])[2]]

Comment: To understand the Muechian grouping technique read http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml. That way you should understand the part `Object[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', Property[@Name = 'COUNTRY'])[1])]`. The second expression `key('k1',Property[@Name='REGION'])[2]` simply ensures there is more than one item in the group as you asked for "If the country meets once - did not write", so the apply-templates only processes elements for which at least a second item exists (done with the `[2]` check.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kObjByCountry" match="Object" use="Property[@Name='COUNTRY']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vCountries" select=
   "/*/*/*/data/Object
          [generate-id()
          = generate-id(key('kObjByCountry', Property[@Name='COUNTRY'])[1])
          ]"/>
  <select>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vCountries">
      <xsl:sort select="Property[@Name='COUNTRY']"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
    </select>

     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vCountries" mode="desc">
      <xsl:sort select="Property[@Name='COUNTRY']"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Object">
   <xsl:variable name="v2nd"
        select="key('kObjByCountry', Property[@Name='COUNTRY'])[2]"/>
   <option value="{(@Id[$v2nd]|Property[@Name='WWW'])[1]}">
    <xsl:value-of select="Property[@Name='COUNTRY']"/>
   </option>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template mode="desc" 
    match="Object[key('kObjByCountry', Property[@Name='COUNTRY'])[2]]">
   <div id="sity_{@Id}">
     <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "key('kObjByCountry', Property[@Name='COUNTRY'])
                                    /Property[@Name='NAME']">
        <xsl:sort/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Property[@Name='NAME']">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template mode="desc"
    match="Object[not(key('kObjByCountry', Property[@Name='COUNTRY'])[2])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<page>
    <elements>
        <element name="bids">
            <data>
                <Object Id="id1">
                    <Property Name="NAME" Order="0">Paris</Property>
                    <Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
                    <Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
                </Object>
                <Object Id="id1">
                    <Property Name="NAME" Order="0">Lion</Property>
                    <Property Name="COUNTRY">France</Property>
                    <Property Name="WWW" >http://france.fr</Property>
                </Object>
                <Object Id="id2">
                    <Property Name="NAME" Order="0">Berlin</Property>
                    <Property Name="COUNTRY">Germany</Property>
                    <Property Name="WWW" >http://germany.gr</Property>
                </Object>
            </data>
        </element>
    </elements>
</page>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result -- in which the countries/cities are sorted**:

```
<select>
   <option value="id1">France</option>
   <option value="http://germany.gr">Germany</option>
</select>
<div id="sity_id1">
   <p>Lion</p>
   <p>Paris</p>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** and **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)** s.

Proper use of **[`xsl:sort`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-sort)**.